# Deregister all registered queries

Tags: marklogic

Is It possible to deregister all registered queries ([cts.register](https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/cts.register))? You can find something like this in the documentation:

> After the cts:register call returns, there is no way to query the system to find the registered query IDs.

But I just want to clean all registered queries

Comment: Why would you need to do this? There’s not a performance impact of having no longer used registered queries.

Comment: But If cache grow too much some of my queries may be deleted from cache.

Comment: So to keep your queries from being deregistered you want to deregister them all?

Comment: After some variable changed I need to re-register queries. In docs there are not written how queries are deregistered from cache. I just want to prevent system to deregister my registered queries but if it is not a problem I will just register queries without deregistering them.

Comment: There’s no real benefit to deregistering. Registered queries can handle an updating database. Unused ones don’t waste resources and the LRU cache will expire them before more used ones. I think you’re overthinking things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`cts.deregister()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.deregister)

Unfortunately, I don't think there isn't an easy way to list all the IDs of registered queries. So, you would need to know what queries you have used to register.

Another option is to restart the cluster.

> Registered queries are persisted as a soft state only; they can become unregistered through an explicit direction (using `cts:deregister`), as a result of the cache growing too large, or because of a server restart.